# Informatica Data Validation option

Tags: testing, etl, data-warehouse, informatica

I want to try `DVO 9.6` and I have an error:

```
Severity: DEBUG
Timestamp: 10/1/2017 1:59:07 PM
Node: node01_DESKTOP-U5UQ90O
Thread: MAPPING
Process ID: 5748
Message Code: DBG_21366
Message:   Note: Input column [NEXTVAL] default value is [ERROR('transformation error')]. Row will be skipped if input value is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats a debug message, not an error. Its informing you that whenever NEXTVAL is NULL it will be skipped (as per the default value you've set for this column, it should error out if it is null).

Comment: How can i handle that! it's a critical task and i wanna solve it

Comment: You can change your powercenter logging level to terse if the debug messages are bothering you